# How to list files in a directory that begin with a character but the filename is then followed by 8 lower-case characters?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

From the Linux CLI, using the *bash* shell, how to list files (using the **ls** command) in a directory where the filenames desired all begin with a character P but the rest of the filename is then followed by 8 lower-case characters?
Tried the following but it does not work.

```
ls -las P[a-z]{8}
```

An example directory would have files like so:

```
Pasdfghjk    
Pqwertyui    
Pabcd    
Pads
```

where only the first two files are desired to be listed/returned to STDOUT.
If the **ls** command cannot do this then what command or command sequence can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash globs don't have a finite repetition operator (`{8}`), even with `extglob` enabled.

So you can pipe `ls` through `grep`:

```
ls -ls | grep -E 'P[a-z]{8}$'
```

(That's not perfect because it will match filenames which end with the pattern. But that might not be important in your case.)

Or you could expand the glob manually:

```
ls -ls P[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]
```

Comment: Your initial suggestion worked well.  I wanted to avoid your second suggestion (although that works also).

Answer (score 6):

With GNU find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regextype sed -regex './P[a-z]\{8\}' -printf "%f\n"
```